# picking a shardkey for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, iot, sharding, distributed-system, bigdata

I want to shard my MongoDB database. I have a high insert rate and want to distribute my documents on two shards evenly.

I have considered rangebase sharding, because I have range queries; but I can not find a solution for picking a good shard key.

```
{
    Timestamp : ISODate("2016-10-02T00:01:00.000Z"),
    Machine_ID: "100",
    Temperature:"50"
}
```

If this is my document and I have 100,000 different machines, would the Machine_ID be a suitable shardkey? And if so, how will MongoDB distribute it on the shards, i.e. do i have to specify the shard range myself? like put Machine_ID 0-49,999 on shard A, and 50,000-100,000 on shard B?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Machine_ID` would be a suitable shard key if your queries afterwards will be per Machine, i.e. get all the temperatures for a specific machine for a certain time range. Reading more about shard keys can be found here: [Choosing shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#choosing-a-shard-key)

MongoDB has two kinds of sharding: Hashed sharding and Range sharding which you can read more about here: [Sharding strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#sharding-strategy). Having said that, you don't need to specify the range of the shards yourself, mongo will take care of it. Especially when a time comes when you'll need to add a new shard, mongo will rearrange the chunks into the new shard.

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster has only two shards, then it isn't difficult to design for. However, if your data will continue to grow and you end up having a lot more shards, then the choice of shard key is more difficult.

For example, if some machines have many more records than others (e.g. one machine has 3000 records i.e. 3% of the total), then that doesn't cause problems with only two shards. But if your data grows so that you need 100 shards, and one machine still has 3% of the total, then Machine_ID is no longer a good choice: because a single machine's records have to be a single chunk, and cannot be distributed across several shards.

In that case, a better strategy might be to use a hash of the Timestamp - but it depends on the overall shape of your dataset.